# multi-factor pre-authorization by braintree

Tags: payment-gateway, braintree

Are there any controls like authorizing the customer from $10 to $15 (eg: 10.75) and asking the user to input the decimal value (.75) to validate the customer during pre-authorization by Braintree during credit-card validation?

Answer (score 0):

There are unfortunately no default tools for that. But reading the [docs](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/vault/card-verification), the mechanism for validating a credit card payment is easy:

> The gateway verifies credit cards by running either a $0 or $1 authorization and then automatically voiding it.

So I created a small script that should fit your needs (tested):

```
$rdm = mt_rand(1,99);
$payment = Braintree_Transaction::sale(array(
    'amount' => floatval(mt_rand(10,14) . '.' . $rdm), // e.g. 14.56
    'paymentMethodNonce' => Input::get('payment_method_nonce'),
));
if($payment->success) {
    $void = Braintree_Transaction::void($payment->transaction->id);
    if($void->success) {
        // store $rdm in DB for later verification
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to [contact support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sup>

This is not supported in Braintree.

While you may have seen this type of functionality in other sites, it is generally used to validate bank accounts, where an actual deposit and deduction occurs. There are a number of reasons why I strongly discourage hand-implementing this feature rather than using our built in [credit card verification](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/ios+ruby/guides/payment-methods#credit-card-verification) and [fraud prevention](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/ios+ruby/guides/advanced-fraud-tools/overview) tools.

- Because the transaction is voided immediately, before it settles, your customers may not even see the transaction on their account, depending on how the processor and their issuing bank handle the transaction.
- A $10-15 charge is a large amount to charge a customer for verification purposes. You may encounter some unhappy customers if this is implemented and not communicated clearly to them.
- You may be flagged as "risky" by Braintree and/or issuing banks and experience difficulties processing transactions.

I recommend [reaching out to support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) to provide details on your application and what are looking to achieve. They should be able to help you determine your best options for processing and verifying credit cards.